# Where is Direct Dependencies in XCode 4.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I cant find it in XCode 4.3.2.
In previous versions of XCode it looked like.

But where it is now?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! 
Go to project->target->build phases->target dependencies
[image]